# How to read output in nodejs from spawned child when output is a file?

Tags: node.js

Trying to spawn a process with node and read its output.
I would like the output to be in a file and to be able to read it.

This is the code I have so far, but it throws an error -

```
const outFile = fs.openSync('out.log', 'a')
const errFile = fs.openSync('err.log', 'a')
const child = childProcess.spawn('node', [pathToJsFile], {
  stdio: ['ignore', outFile, errFile],
  detached: true
})
child.unref()
console.log(child.stdio)
console.log('waiting for output')
child.stdio[1].on('data', (data)=> { // ==> get error since stdio[1] is null
```

As mentioned in the comment, when I look in `child.stdio` I see `[null, null, null]`
However, when I look at the file, I can see the output is written.
I am using node 4.2.1

What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You are wiring up the child process's output to a filesystem file `'out.log'`, so it goes there and therefore is not also directly available via stdout. You'll need to directly read the output file by filesystem path using the `fs` core module. `var outBuffer = fs.readSync('out.log');`